# Query database by SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, database, ado.net, sqldatareader

I am trying to get data from database using SqlDataReader and display it in a ListBox control. My database has two tables Genre (Id, Name) and Review (Id, Title, GenreId). My C# code looks like this:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection connection =
        new SqlConnection(@"Server=" + txtServerName.Text + ";Database=" + txtDatabase.Text + "; Integrated Security=SSPI"))
        using (SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand("Select Genre.Name, Review.Title  " +
                           "From Genre Inner Join Review " +
                           "On Genre.Id = Review.GenreId;", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            MessageBox.Show("Connected successful!");

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string sFormat = String.Format("Name: {0} Title: {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));

                    // adding data to ListBox
                    lst.Items.Add(sFormat);
                }
            }
        }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

When running code above, I only got the Name column and the Title column doesn't appear. But if I changed the sFormat variable as follows:

```
string sFormat = String.Format("Title: {0} Name: {1}", reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(0));
```

and I got both the Name column and the Title column.

I don't know why? Please help me!

Comment: What do you mean? is title doesn't have a value?

Comment: Is the Name terminated by a newline character?

Comment: try sqlreader["title"]

Comment: Did you check for @spodger's comment? Replace `reader.GetString(0)` with `reader.GetString(0).TrimEnd()`. Does that help?

Comment: Thank @spodger and LocEngineer. Good comments!

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this works

```
string sFormat = String.Format("Title: {0} Name: {1}", reader["Name"].ToString(), reader["Title"].ToString());
```

Comment: Thank Andrew, but your answer and mine are the same. If I run your code, I get data from the Name column only; but if changed string sFormat = String.Format(..., reader["Title"].ToString(),reader["Name"].ToString()) then I will get both columns. The problem here is the order between reader["Name"] and reader["Title"].